# Bash scripting : Ignore deletion of unix accounts during account removal process

Tags: bash, awk

Need to clear user accounts on a Linux box with few exceptions . Script to do the same for me is

```
#UIDMAX will contain the minimum value used by OS for ID selection
UIDMIN=`grep "UID_MIN" /etc/login.defs`

#UIDMAX will contain the mixnimum value used by OS for ID selection
UIDMAX=`grep "UID_MAX" /etc/login.defs`

for i in  awk -F: -v "min=${UIDMIN##UID_MIN}" -v "max=${UIDMAX##UID_MAX}" '{ if ( $3 >= min && $3 <=max ) print $1}' /etc/passwd
do 
     userdel -r $i  
done
```

But I want to add few exceptions stored in a variable which should be ignored by the script during removal of user account process . `e.g exceptions="test1 test2 test"`
I want that `userdel` will ignore the users mentioned in `exceptions` variable during execution of above script

Comment: The awk command in the `for` loop will not work. You need to use the command substitution operator `$()` (or backticks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why use awk?

```
# using lower-case variable names is conventional for things which are neither builtins
# nor environment variables to avoid namespace conflicts.
min=$(grep "^UID_MIN" /etc/login.defs); min=${min##*[[:space:]]}
max=$(grep "^UID_MAX" /etc/login.defs); max=${max##*[[:space:]]}

# set up an associative array of users to ignore
declare -A users_to_ignore=( [test1]=1 [test2]=1 [test]=1 )

while IFS=: read -r name _ pid _ <&3; do
  # check not only for pid min and max, but also presence in users_to_ignore
  if (( pid >= min && pid < max )) && ! [[ ${users_to_ignore[$name]} ]]; then
    userdel -r "$name"
  fi
done 3</etc/passwd
```

If you wanted to work on systems using different directory sources (NIS, LDAP, etc) and your operating system provides `getent`, you might use `3< <(getent passwd)` rather than `3</etc/passwd`; more flexible that way.

---

If you want to support versions of bash older than 4.0, then one can use:

```
users_to_ignore="test1 test2 test"
```

...and...

```
[[ " $users_to_ignore " =~ " $name " ]]
```

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to declare `users_to_ignore` as a simple string? You could use the `=~` operator to check whether `$name` should be ignored..

Comment: @hek2mgl, think about what happens if you have a name that's a subset of another name; ie. "hek2mgl" and "hek", and want to preserve only the shorter-named user. Suddenly you have to worry about matching surrounding whitespace as well as the name itself (and corner cases for the first and last names), and then it's easier just to Do It Right and use an array.

Comment: you can use word boundaries in regexes. I don't see a problem with this.

Comment: Does ERE have word boundary support? I thought that was a PCRE thing.

Comment: Hmm. Okay -- GNU's ERE does; POSIX ERE doesn't. That's a fair place for folks to have differing opinions on how to paint the bikeshed.

Comment: The `\b` option is PCRE specific, but it can be simulated using `(^| )` for the start boundary and `($| )` for the end boundary. (Having words delimited by spaces).

Comment: @hek2mgl, which I'm well of aware of, but my personal judgment call is that that's uglier than associative arrays. Added notes on the regex approach, though, to cover all bases (particularly, pre-4.0 compatibility).

Comment: @EdMorton, true, but because I'm using double-quotes around the expansion on the right-hand side of an `=~` within `[[ ]]`, the shell doesn't treat it as a regex but as a literal substring to match. If I were writing, say, `[[ $users_to_ignore =~ " "$name" " ]]` (with the expansion outside the quotes), then yes, that would be a problem.

Comment: @EdMorton, inside `[[ ]]`, globbing and string-splitting are suppressed regardless.

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple and use awk for what it's good at (parsing text) and shell for what it's good at (sequencing calls to commands):

```
awk -F: -v exceptions="test1 test2 test" '
BEGIN {
    split(exceptions,tmp,/ /)
    for (i in tmp) {
        except[tmp[i]]
    }
}
NR==FNR {
   if ( sub(/UIDMIN/,"") ) min = $0
   if ( sub(/UIDMAX/,"") ) max = $0
   next
}
$3 >= min && $3 <=max && !($1 in except) {print $1}
' /etc/login.defs /etc/passwd |
while IFS= read -r name
do 
     userdel -r "$name"  
done
```

Note that the above is just me trying to translate your command since you didn't provide any sample input and output so check it for yourself before executing.

Comment: Where are you checking against the blacklist of names to ignore?

Comment: The OP -- in the textual part of the question -- is asking how to extend their code to not delete specifically named users even with UIDs inside the relevant range.

Comment: This is more efficient than the pure-bash approach inasmuch as it's extracting UIDMIN and UIDMAX in only one pass through the file with no separate subshells required (which _could_ be done in native bash, but would require significantly more code). Any other advantages?

Comment: It's portable and will work with any awk and shell AFAIK (except old, broken, awk of course). It's also very easily maintainable/extensible.

Comment: Fair. I'd have to use `expr substring` to work with shells lacking the ksh `[[ ]]` extension, and even that is a hole carved out in the POSIX spec for expr to _allow_ its implementation, as opposed to a requirement.

Comment: Any advantages to the all-shell-ish (ignoring the greps) approach?

Comment: I think the largest advantage is simply that it's using/teaching tools within a language the user is already leveraging (the shell), rather than splitting the knowledge to ingest across two categories. There are smaller things -- being able to maintain state within the loop that can be used later in the enclosing shell script is one; if we truly are ignoring the greps, avoiding fork/exec overhead is another.

Comment: Hmm, you could make the same case for a shell read/comparison loop over `grep` or `sed`. I just use awk for text manipulation because it's easy to write in, efficient, portable, has a small C-like language so it's easy to learn, has very few gotchas but has a ton of built-in support for text manipulation (e.g. reading a paragraph at a time just by specifying `RS=""`). IMHO anyone who has to manipulate text will be much happier if they learn awk than if they don't but horses for courses I suppose... Thanks for the discussion and all the info in this thread.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree that awk's efficiency is often a killer feature when working on large streams -- a few shells (ksh93, zsh) may be able to come close in terms of performance overhead, but bash isn't even in the same league. It's been a good discussion; take care.